# batch file to delete files and folders except zip files

Tags: batch-file

I've created a batch file which unzips all files

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM
REM Remove the double quotes from the front and end of the root path
REM
SET ROOT=%1
SET ROOT=%ROOT:~1%
SET ROOT=%ROOT:~0,-1%
ECHO %ROOT%

REM Searching directory structure from root for subfolders and zipfiles,
REM then extracting the zipfiles into a subfolder of the same name as the zipfile.

FOR /F "delims==" %%d IN ('dir /ogne /ad /b /s "%ROOT%"') DO (
ECHO Extracting : "%%d"

FOR /F "delims==" %%f IN ('dir /b "%%d\*.zip"') DO (
        REM Getting filename without extension.
        SET subfolder=%%~nf
        ECHO mkdir "%%d\!subfolder!"
    mkdir "%%d\!subfolder!"
        REM Extracting zipfile content to the newly created folder.
        ECHO 7z x "%%d\%%f" -o "%%d\!subfolder!"
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "%%d\%%f" -o"%%d\!subfolder!"
)
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Now I want to delete the files which has been created.

Can anyone help in deleting the unzipped files alone and not the zipped files and also care should be taken that it should not delete the root and the zip file.

Any other solution is also appreciated.

I want the zip files only within the folders. All other files can be deleted without user saying Y/N.

Comment: `SET ROOT=%~1` should set `ROOT` to dequoted(parameter 1) - regardless of whether the parameter WAS actually quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and remove the `echo`s if the output is OK:

```
for /r "%root%" %%i in (*.zip) do (
    echo del /f /q "%%~dpni\*.*"
    echo rd /q "%%~dpni"
)
```

Comment: I'd suggest that the `del` line may be redundant and `rd /q` should be `rd /s /q`

Comment: I get "The full path of  is too long."
Actually i don't know anything about the batch file writing i just know to use it,.. :) so pls help in writing full code rather than snippets :)